How can I update new keywords of Mathematica to LaTeX?
I have posted this question
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2Win}
\lstset{language=Mathematica}
\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos={t},
    frame={lines},
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    framerule=0.5pt,
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
        SolveValues[Sqrt[8  x^2 - 3  x - 10] == -2 + 3  x, x, Reals]
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


The keyword SolveValues not bold. I input morekeywords={SolveValues} by hand in LaTeX. How can I tell Mathematica update new Keywords.


Just add morekeywords={SolveValues} in the definition?
in this list you can manually add other ones.  The definition is done only one time. You can save that in the preamble. So you only need to add it one time. Other than this, you have to edit the listings style file itself which contains the language=Mathematica default settings.
But why do that? it is just as easy to add morekeywords={SolveValues} in your preamble.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2Win}
\lstset{language=Mathematica}
\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos={t},
    frame={lines},    
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    framerule=0.5pt,
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    morekeywords={SolveValues}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
        SolveValues[Sqrt[8  x^2 - 3  x - 10] == -2 + 3  x, x, Reals]
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

gives

Btw, it is better to define listing style. This way you can have different styles for different languages within the same document without them clashing with each others. Like this
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2Win}

\lstdefinestyle{MMA}{%
    language=Mathematica,%
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos={t},
    frame={lines},    
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    framerule=0.5pt,
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    morekeywords={SolveValues}
}

\lstnewenvironment{MMA}{%
  \lstset{style=MMA}}{}


\begin{document}
    \begin{MMA}
        SolveValues[Sqrt[8  x^2 - 3  x - 10] == -2 + 3  x, x, Reals]
    \end{MMA}
\end{document}

In my env. I have 10 different custom listing styles for 10 different languages. (Fortran, C++, Java, Maple, etc...)

I hope, your code can update new keywords automatically. In this code VectorAngle and InfinitePlane not bold. I must input by hand.
\begin{MMA} Clear["Global`*"]; aa = {0, 0, 0}; bb = {a, 0, 0}; c = {a, a, 0}; d = {0, a, 0}; s = {0, 0, h}; u = Cross[s - bb, s - c]; v = Cross[s - aa, s - c]; SolveValues[VectorAngle[u, v] == Pi/3, h, Reals,  Assumptions -> {a > 0, h > 0}]  SAB = InfinitePlane[{s, aa, bb}];  \end{MMA}

@JohnPaulPeter You have to add these morekeywords={SolveValues,VectorAngle,InfinitePlane}  basically you have to do it once.  How else will listing know which to make bold and which is not? Someone has to tell it. If it is not in the style file itself. Since Mathematica with each new version adds more new commands, only way to do it, is to update the list. My Maple list is 3 pages long of keywords.

Thank you for your comment.
